# Convert .flv to .mp4

Tags: iphone, flv, mp4

Is there a good tool that I can try out to convert my .flv file to .mp4? I need to use it on a mac, so not on a windows PC.

I have made an iPhone application and I want to try out how a webcast of 40 minutes streams on it. To do this i must convert my .flv file to .mp4.

I have found a converter ([This one](http://www.iskysoft.com/convert-flv/convert-flv-to-mp4-on-mac.html)) but if you use it as trial you can only edit 3 minutes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like [handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php). I have used a converted video in my app.

Answer (score 5):

I've done this in the past using ffmpeg:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Since most other free converters I've seen so far were built on top of ffmpeg, I'd also recommend to cut out the middle-man and use ffmpeg directly.

Comment: Indeed, they often use very outdated versions of ffmpeg, with poor presets.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have a look at it.